# Convertendo expressão de divisão em C++ para C#

Tags: c#, c++, matemática, operadores

Tenho a seguinte condição em C++ e gostaria de passar para C#. O problema que estou tendo é com a função `div` que apresenta o erro:

> The name 'div' does not exist in the current context

```
if (quant > 0)
{
    return  div(quant, 7).quot;
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema com o `div`?

Comment: Coloque mais informações sobre a questão e esclareça melhor sua dúvida e o problema. Cite exemplos de outras tentativas que fez.

Comment: a div fica sublinhada de vermelho com a seguinte mensagem: The name 'div' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Porque você precisa usar a `div` em C++? Forneci uma resposta que lhe dá o mesmo resultado em C#. Claro que o problema até poderia ser outro. Pelo trecho do código não para para determinar isto. Se o problema for outro, você pode [edit] sua pergunta para colocar o código mais completo e informações que ajudem entender seu problema.

Comment: @user2254936 Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 4):

Pelo que entendi você quer fazer uma divisão e pegar apenas o quociente. Se é isto não vejo motivos para usar a função `div` nem mesmo no C++. O mesmo vale para o C#. Na verdade o C# sequer tem uma função semelhante pronta (a vantagem desta função é devolver tanto o quociente quanto o resto) por isso você tem um erro tentando usá-la.

Portanto em C# você precisa apenas fazer uma divisão simples com o [operador de divisão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#division-operator-?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397). Seu código ficaria assim:

```
if (quant > 0)
{
    return  quant / 7;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Math/Division2.cs).